# Show To and CC separately in open message in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

Have a user here working in Outlook 2016.

When they open a message, the To, CC and BCC names are all grouped together on one line in the message header, making the only way to see who is who if you Reply All.  See pic below

[image]

Where is the option to have this broken out like every other version of Outlook, also shown below?

[image]

This is driving me crazy, I feel like I have looked everywhere, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the Up/Down arrow in the bottom right corner of mail header area. This button will show full header info.

Comment: Ha, I knew it had to be something so obvious and simple, thanks